# Angular CLI Local Server (ng serve --host 0.0.0.0)

Tags: angular, performance, github, connection, webserver

I have developed an Angular page to practice some Angular 2+ and explore the Google Firebase realtime database. You can see the project here: https://github.com/Kiril1512/AreYouSolid

If you read the description you can see that this is a simple 15 question Quiz about SOLID principles and you can submit you result to the database and compare it with other people.

I want to run a local server with this with the following command:`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --aot`. So with this I can just give my local IP to them and they can access my server and do the Quiz. And I know that this works because I can access with any laptop in the local network to my server. I don't know nothing about how this is handled and how it works.

Questions:

- Since this is a local development server running on my laptop, how many connections it can handle?
- Can for example 15 people access it in the same time with no problems?

PS: If this is a bad approach/decision maybe I will look for some free domain service to temporary storage this so they can access it or even GitHub pages if its possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the answer above, create an local CLI server is a bad practice. So the solution I found that fit my problem was to deploy my application to GitHub pages following this angular tutorial:

https://angular.io/guide/deployment#deploy-to-github-pages.

Answer (score 1):

That's actually a bad practice indeed.

If you want to hand your application to others, you better build it and run it in a local server.

First, you have to build your application using: `ng build --prod`.

Then, you can run your application using a lot of different tools, you can use either Chrome web server ([link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en)) or http-server package ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)).

You shouldn't be limited to any amount of users running your local server, for 15 people it should work alright.

Comment: And what do you think about GitHub pages? Is this a good option?

Comment: It's not local, but, it's good for hosting static websites for sure.

Comment: Angular also released the ng deploy option, which can deploy a website easily for ya to some hosting services. You can read more about it here: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#automatic-deployment-with-the-cli

Comment: Thank you! I followed your link and created an GitHub Page to deploy my app.